# NodeJS: Validate certificate in DER format

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, der

I'm using `crypto` module to validate a certificate, but both, my certificate and my public key are in **DER** format. It seems that `crypto` module does not accept this format.

Is there a way (or module) to convert DER to PEM format using NodeJS? I couldn't find any and cannot use command line to call *openssl* via shell.

**UPDATE:** It's not about HTTPS certificates. It's about general X.509 certificates. And if you mark the question as negative, please leave a comment to justify it. Don't be a stupid if you are not able to help.

Comment: I'd leave out the "UPDATE" part if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominykas' answer was good, but in my case, I have a certificate that uses **[ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography)** and **`node-forge`** does not support it. 
So I've found a module called **[`node-openssl-wrapper`](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-openssl-wrapper)**, which worked perfectly well because it encapsulates the openssl commands in a simple function call, like this:

```
co(function*() {
  var ossl = require('openssl-wrapper');
  var derCert = new Buffer('...'); // binary DER certificate
  var pemCert = yield ossl.qExec('x509', derCert, { inform: 'der', outform: 'pem' });
});
```

Comment: I think this answer works for me, but when I use this pemCert in crypto.publicDecrypt(pemkey, cipherText) and it says: (pemkey) is not a buffer. Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance. @blzn

Comment: Maybe you should try `crypto.publicDecrypt(new Buffer(pemkey), cipherText)`.

Answer (score 22):

I think the PEM format is just the DER binary data that has been base64 encoded, split into 64 character lines, and wrapped between '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' and '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.

So you could do this:

```
var prefix = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n';
var postfix = '-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
var pemText = prefix + derBuffer.toString('base64').match(/.{0,64}/g).join('\n') + postfix;
```

You will not need to put a '\n' before the postfix because the last match of the der buffer should be an empty string '', so there will be a '\n' at the end of `derBuffer.toString('base64').match(/.{0,64}/g).join('\n')`

Comment: Fantastic, this should be the answer. Works with any DER to PEM, e.g X509 CRL

Comment: I was looking for a library to convert DER to PEM and felt like looking for [is-odd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-odd) after seeing this.

Comment: @JohnB this should be the answer if it had been posted 3 years earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of doing it:

```js
function derToPem(der) {
 var forge = require("node-forge");
 var derKey = forge.util.decode64(der);
 var asnObj = forge.asn1.fromDer(derKey);
 var asn1Cert = forge.pki.certificateFromAsn1(asnObj);
 return forge.pki.certificateToPem(asn1Cert);
};
```

Comment: Good try, but it doesn't support ECDSA for public keys.