# How to convert a .crt string into a .der certificate binary and save it into Redis?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to convert a .crt string into a .der certificate and save it into Redis. I'm try to replicate the following steps with Nodejs

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
openssl rsa -outform DER -in key.pem -out key.der
redis-cli -x HMSET domain:testsite1.com cert < testsite1.com.der
redis-cli -x HMSET domain:testsite1.com key < testsite1.com.key.der
```

The **.crt** string looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is my failed attempt using `node-forge` npm and `redis`.

```
var certDER = forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1('/opt/resty/ssl/*.ngdeploy.com.chained.crt',{encoding: 'utf8'}));
REDIS.hmset('test','cert',certDER);
```

I tried Googling for solutions but I didn't find any for converting **.crt** string to **.der** binary. I'm looking for a Node.js solution and not an OpenSSL solution. Please advise.

Comment: Split these 3 certificates (one cert will be `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- XXXXXXXXXXX -----END CERTIFICATE-----. Keep the formating - 64 characters per line) and call `openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der` on each of them. It should work.

Comment: @pepo I'm looking for a node.js solution not using openssl cli.

Answer (score 2):

The extension of a file is often meaningless. What you seam to look for is a way to convert from text or PEM format (Base64) to binary or DER.

The simplest way is to use Openssl but if you must use JS [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992865) might help just make sure you reverse the conversion (PEM to DER , instead of DER to PEM)