# NodeJS and TLS, get client certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2

I'm testing `Node.JS` and `TLS` and are creating a simple server and client.
This seems to work fine:

server.js:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server-certs/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server-certs/server.crt'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: true
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');

  console.log(socket.getPeerCertificate(true).raw);

  socket.write('welcome!\n');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

client.js:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./client-certs/client.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./client-certs/client.crt')
};

const socket = tls.connect(8000, options, () => {
  console.log('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.on('end', () => {
  console.log('server ends connection');
});
```

With the `server.js` I print out the client cert:

```
console.log(socket.getPeerCertificate(true).raw);
```

But doing `cat client.crt` on Linux I have the following long string:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICsDCCAZgCCQC8miOEYnXCXDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
...
MHBcIlA2R3ssgfhlcSJcaR59LKA=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Is it possible for the `server.js` to get that string from the client certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(socket.getPeerCertificate(true).raw);
```

This returns the certificate in DER format. What you see in `client.crt` is the certificate in PEM format - which is basically base64 of the binary DER format with some header and footer line added. You could convert the PEM to DER using `openssl x509 -in client.crt -outform der`. Or you could convert the DER formatted certificate to PEM in nodejs as suggested in [NodeJS: Validate certificate in DER format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992865/nodejs-validate-certificate-in-der-format).

Comment: `var prefix = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n'; var postfix = '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'; var pemText = prefix + socket.getPeerCertificate(true).raw.toString('base64').match(/.{0,64}/g).join('\n') + postfix;` seems to work, thank you.