# How to validate a PEM certificate in an input filed?

Tags: angular, ssl, ssl-certificate

I do have an input field within angular app (v8) where I upload a **pem certificate** (**.pem** extension).

I would like to check if the uploaded file is valid or not. Using a RegExp is an option but it's a kind of not 100% sure.

My question, is if there is any library (maybe via npm) which validate a PEM certificate and throws an error on the fly if not valid, otherwise passes, or if there is a better option/concept for that?

The certificate should start:

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
```

followed by a base64 encoded string and ends with:

```
----END CERTIFICATE----
```

I have been searching on SO and found some useful hints:

[Validate certificate in DER format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992865/nodejs-validate-certificate-in-der-format)

[Manually verify SSL Self Signed certificate signature](http://How%20do%20we%20validate%20the%20format%20of%20the%20CSR%20using%20Regex)

but as said, a library would be more efficient.

Comment: A _correct_ PEM file has the base64 broken into lines of 64 characters, except the last; see rfc7468 section 2 (or wiklipedia!). But some programs don't require or check this, so people don't agree on whether this is included in 'valid'.